# Dynamic SQL query in SQL Server 2008 stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 4 tables A, B, C and X.

**X** table :

```
Icid    Trade_Id    Counter_Party
---------------------------------
1         101       HDFC1
2         102       HDFC1
3         103       HDFC2
4         104       HDFC2
5         105       HDFC2
6         106       HDFC3
7         107       HDFC4
8         108       HDFC4
9         109       HDFC5
10        110       HDFC5
```

**A** table :

```
Icid    Trade_Id      Name
----------------------------------
 1       110          HDFC Bank Pvt Ltd
 2       105          HDFC Bank Pvt Ltd
 3       101          HDFC Bank Pvt Ltd
 4       102          HDFC Bank Pvt Ltd
```

**B** table:

```
Icid    Trade_Id    Name
----------------------------------------
 1        103       HSBC Pvt Ltd
 2        104       HSBC Pvt Ltd
 3        106       HSBC Pvt Ltd
```

**C** table :

```
Icid    Trade_Id    Name
--------------------------------------
 1       107        HK Pvt Ltd
 2       108        HK Pvt Ltd
 3       109        HK Pvt Ltd
```

A, B, C table like this and I have created another table and store tables name as below.

**Findtbl** table:

```
    Icid    Table_name
    ------------------
     2       A
     3       B
     4       C
```

I need to table **X** `Trade_ID` find to tables A, B and C. If found in table A, then print location column `INDIA`, if found in table B then print location column `USA`, and if found in table C, then location column is `Hongkong` in `#Temp` table location, Trade_Id, Name columns:

**#temp** table :

```
Icid    location    Trade_Id    Name
```

I tried this:

```
Declare @Fst_value nvarchar(100)
Declare @Counter INT
Declare @tablename nvarchar(20)
Declare @sql nvarchar(max)
Declare @isvalue int
Declare @loop int = 1
Declare @sqlsecond nvarchar(max)
Declare @sqlthird nvarchar(max)

SET @Fst_value = '104'
SET @Counter = (Select COUNT(Icid) From Findtbl)

WHILE @Loop < = @Counter
BEGIN
    SET @tablename = (SELECT Table_name 
                      FROM Findtbl 
                      WHERE Icid = @Loop)
    SET @sql = 'Select @isvalue = Icid,@sqlsecond = Trade_Id,@sqlthird = Name  From '+@tablename+' Where Trade_Id = '+@Fst_value+''

    Execute sp_executesql @sql,N'@isvalue int OUTPUT,@sqlsecond nvarchar OUTPUT,@sqlthird nvarchar OUTPUT',@isvalue = @isvalue OUT,@sqlsecond  = @sqlsecond OUT,@sqlthird = @sqlthird OUT

    if(@isvalue <> 0)
    begin
        Select @sql
        break
    end

    SET @isvalue = 0
    SET @Loop = @Loop + 1
END
```

This code is contained in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give it a shot, though you probably need to spend some time re-stating your question.

I'm going to have to ignore the procedural code, and use set-based code.

```
insert into #temp (Icid, location, Trade_Id, Name)
select case
    when A.Trade_ID is not null then A.Icid
    when B.Trade_ID is not null then B.Icid
    when C.Trade_ID is not null then C.Icid
end
,case
    when A.Trade_ID is not null then 'INDIA'
    when B.Trade_ID is not null then 'USA'
    when C.Trade_ID is not null then 'Hongkong'
end
,case
    when A.Trade_ID is not null then A.Trade_ID
    when B.Trade_ID is not null then B.Trade_ID
    when C.Trade_ID is not null then C.Trade_ID
end
,case
    when A.Trade_ID is not null then A.Name
    when B.Trade_ID is not null then B.Name
    when C.Trade_ID is not null then C.Name
end
from X
left outer join A on X.Trade_ID on A.Trade_ID
left outer join B on X.Trade_ID on B.Trade_ID
left outer join C on X.Trade_ID on C.Trade_ID
```